# aws codedeploy - running sql scripts

Tags: aws-code-deploy

I run my sql scripts which inserts data to DB as a part of my codedeploy lifecycle event on a Autoscaling group. The Autoscaling group has 2 instances, the sql scripts run fine on the 1st instance and the deployment is successful on that instance.
In the 2nd instance, as the DB has the data already inserted the sql script fails with the below error message:

[stderr]ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 32: Duplicate entry

Any workaround or solution will be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It suggests that the DB already has an entry which you're trying to insert, hence that error. You may like to first check if the DB has that entry or not.

To identify which part of the script is giving you this error, you may try to create subset of your script and identify the actual cause.

This certainly is the issue when you already have some record(s) and the DB / Table / schema does not allow for duplicate entry.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your deployment group is a OneAtATime deployment type, then your lifecycle hook should check for the entry *before* it inserts the SQL.

That way, only the first deployed instance will apply the change. The other deployments will test for the entry, and then skip the insert code phase.